# jQuery Syntax Meaning

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you read this JavaScript code? (var1 ? var2:var3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490853/how-do-you-read-this-javascript-code-var1-var2var3)
>   [JS How to use the ?: (ternary) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/js-how-to-use-the-ternary-operator)

I was looking at a website's code and found this:

```
$.body = $('body');    
$.scroll = ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.msie) ? $('html') : $.body;
```

What is the second line saying? Looks like some sort of if statement

Thanks

Comment: It is the JavaScript ternary operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/javascript-ternary-operator

Comment: @JustinEthier Might as well post that as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the link @JustinEthier - I didn't know what the term was called.

Comment: @Chad - I was going to, but questions about the ternary operator seem to come up so frequently that this question will probably end up being closed...

Comment: @user906080 - No worries, it's basically impossible to search for `?` unless you already know the operator by name...

Answer (score 3):

If the browser is mozilla, or if the browser is msie, then select the html dom object, else, select the body.

```
var a = CONDITION ? IF_TRUE : IF_FALSE;
```

Answer (score 3):

It could have also been written as (but most people would prefer the style that you posted):

```
if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.msie) {
    $.scroll = $('html');
} else {
    $.scroll = $.body;
}
```